# JPEG won't show in IE8 (but it is RGB)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, jpeg

I have a page with my portfolio. I want to show people two projects at the time with a picture beside it.
Under my projects, there is a "Load more" button.
Everything works in IE9, Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE8 (maybe IE7 as well).
See example: link deleted

The JPEGs of the projects wont load in ie8, but the other images do. It's strange. The format of the JPEGs is RGB. Even a `.png` doesn't work.

The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
$(".projecten").slice(0, 2).show(); // select the first five
$("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".projecten:hidden").slice(0, 2).show(); // select next 5 hidden divs and show them
    if($(".projecten:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
        alert("Alle projecten zijn nu geladen."); // alert if there are none left
    }
});
   });
</script>

<style type"text/css">
.projecten { 
display:none;
z-index:5;
}
</style>

<h1>Projecten</h1><br>
            <p>Some text</p><br>

  <div class="projecten"><div id="inhoud"><table width="924" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
    <tr>
    <td width="210" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top"><img src="Figuren/Projecten/Parallelweg 2e fase.jpg" width="210" height="297" longdesc="Parallelweg 2e fase"></td>
    <td width="35"></td>
    <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top"><b>Parallelweg 's-Hertogenbosch 2e fase </b>
        <i>text.... </i><br>text......
      </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
</div>
     </div>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Meer projecten laten zien ... That part works for me IE9 64bit.

Comment: Are you sure you're dealing with jpeg files, and not another format with the jpeg extension?

Comment: @bfavaretto He gave the URI, so you can see (e. g. in GIMP) that they are really JPEGs. However, I wonder, does this IE8 display JPEG or PNG images on other Web sites? The image filter could be borken.

Comment: @PointedEars It looks like it was the whitespace in the filename. Original URI does not work anymore, OP seems to have renamed the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces from the image filenames. The images on your site that do not have spaces in the filenames appear just fine for me.

Change:

```
<img src="Figuren/Projecten/Parallelweg 2e fase.jpg" width="210" height="297" longdesc="Parallelweg 2e fase">
```

To:

```
<img src="Figuren/Projecten/Parallelweg%202e%20fase.jpg" width="210" height="297" longdesc="Parallelweg 2e fase" />
```

Also see that I closed the `<img />` tag by adding a forward slash before the end of the tag.

Or you could ditch the spaces all together and replace them with something else like an underscore (`_`) or a hyphen (`-`):

```
<img src="Figuren/Projecten/Parallelweg-2e-fase.jpg" width="210" height="297" longdesc="Parallelweg 2e fase" />
```

This would require you to change the file's name on the server so it would be properly referenced.

Comment: The filename does not need to be changed if the space character is URL-encoded as `%20`.

Comment: @PointedEars Valid point. It's really up to the developer what they want to see. `%20`/`-`/`_` are all pretty standard replacements for spaces. Using the escaped char-code has the added benefit that you don't have to change the names of the files on the server. Camel-case is pretty popular too: `Parallelweg2eFase.jpg`. I like using hypens (`-`) because I like the way they make the URL easy to read.

Comment: thanks guys for the very quick response.
i changed it, but with no luck. i see that the pictures are there. But they are hidden. I have to right click > show picture in ie8.

Comment: @user1778188 See if emptying the browser cache helps. And if after emptying the cache no images are displayed at all, check the "Show pictures" checkbox in Tools → Internet Options → Advanced → Multimedia and the like.

Comment: @PointedEars. I tried both. No luck. Maybe the pictures are behind the white background in some way?

Comment: @user1778188 If they were you could not context-click them. But you can try disabling all scripts and stylesheets, then re-enabling them again one by one, to see if they interfere. Be sure to clear the cache  after each step.

Comment: @PointedEars. Ok, i will try. Let you know.

Comment: Oke i fixed it.. in a other way. Not the way it has to be but: i made a new div id. placed the image as a background and it works. thanks a lot guys for your energy and time. Now i have to the next problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094218/vcf-file-wont-download-in-ie8-htcaccess-file-doenst-work